# UI Freeze when Navigation a page to another in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

In my application My MainPage Showing Menus and after clicking menu the next page loading very slow and freeze the UI.

This happen when the content page contain a listView with Items.
My Data Page Content a listView with 50 items(Infinite Scrolling First 50 items)

XAML:

```xml
<ListView  
    ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsData}" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItemsData}"
    HasUnevenRows="True" 
    BackgroundColor="White" x:Name="ItemsDataList">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Grid 
                    Margin="2,0,2,0" 
                    Padding="8" 
                    IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnableItemsData}">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="30*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="30*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="30*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Label Text="{Binding SKU}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" TextColor="{Binding SKUColor}" FontSize="Small"/>
                    <Label Text="{Binding OrderNumber}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" TextColor="Black" FontSize="Small"/>
                    <Label Text="{Binding CategoryName}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" TextColor="Black" FontSize="Small"/>
                    <Label Text="{Binding OrderQuantity}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" TextColor="Black" FontSize="Small"/>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Bin}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="4" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" TextColor="Black" FontSize="Small"/>
                </Grid>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>

    <ListView.Behaviors>
        <eventToCommand:EventToCommandBehavior 
            EventName="ItemSelected" 
            Command="{Binding ItemsDataSelectedItemChange}"/>
        <eventToCommand:EventToCommandBehavior 
            EventName="ItemAppearing" 
            Command="{Binding ItemsDataItemAppearing}"/>
    </ListView.Behaviors>
</ListView>
```

ViewModel:

```cs
public ObservableCollection<ItemsData> Data
{
    get { return _data; }
    set
    {
        _data = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

Getting the data from Local Database

```cs
Data = GetData(GlobalVariable.BranchId, DataLimit, Offset, SearchText, filterData, "Others", sortData);
```

How to get rid of this issues?

Comment: You will have to add the code of the page that you are loading, ContentPage as well as ViewModel so that we can understand better

Comment: I Updated my code please watch this.

Comment: What about the code behind Imean the ViewModel?

Comment: Provide the implementation of GetData, so we can decide if you are loading the data optimally or on the correct thread.

Comment: Try to implement `GetData` method asynchronously. Refer: [async](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/platform/async);